# Inserting values in to a database

Tags: java, mysql, database, sqlite, record

GOT IT WORKING. thanks everyone for the help

I'm new to programming and I'm trying to check if my database is empty. If it is empty, it'll have a record inserted in to it. If not, it should run normal. I'm also checking if the file path exists for my image.

Every time I run the program it keeps adding "John" (John should only be added if the database is empty).

My code:

```
public class Database {

    private ArrayList<Person> people;


    public Database(){
        people = new ArrayList<Person>();


    }


    public void run(){

        Connection connection = null;
        ResultSet resultSet = null;
        Statement statement = null;


        try {
            Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
            connection = DriverManager
                    .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\Peopleinfo.sqlite");


            statement = connection.createStatement();

            if(people.isEmpty()){

                File f = new File ("C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\images\\upload.png");

                if (f.exists()){

                        String sql = "INSERT INTO PeoplesInfo (Name,bio,Image) " +
                                "VALUES ('John','California','C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\images\\upload.png');"; 
                        statement.executeUpdate(sql);

                        System.out.println("Image exists");

                    }
                    else {
                        System.out.println("Image doesn't exist");}

            }


            else if (!people.isEmpty()) {

                String sql = "INSERT INTO PeoplesInfo (Name,bio,Image) " +
                        "VALUES ('Stan','California','C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\images\\upload.png');"; 
                statement.executeUpdate(sql);

                System.out.println("Record added");


            }



            resultSet = statement
                    .executeQuery("SELECT name, bio, image FROM PeoplesInfo");




        while (resultSet.next()) {

                Person p = new Person(resultSet.getString("name"),resultSet.getString("bio"),resultSet.getString("image"));
                people.add(p);


                System.out.println(p.toString());
                System.out.println("Retrieved element is = " + p.getName());       



            }


                        resultSet = statement
                    .executeQuery("SELECT name, bio, image FROM PeoplesInfo");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            try {

                resultSet.close();
                statement.close();
                connection.close();

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }
    }


    public ArrayList<Person> getPeople(){
        return people;




    }

}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like you are checking if your ArrayList is empty not the database. `people.isEmtpy()` is probably always true because you haven't added anything to the ArrayList

Comment: Swap the bit where you fill people with data, and the bit where you insert depending on whether people is empty or not.

Comment: Also, for various reasons, keeping a long lived objectgraph of a copy  the database in memory is going to give you a lot of headaches down the line.

Comment: Mind explaining a bit more about swapping the data? Sorry i'm just a bit confused on that.

Comment: Sorry. Swap the order you execute things in. Right now you're inserting before you have filled any data into the persons array. Just move the block of code that puts data from the db into the arraylist at the top of the method, instead of at the bottom. Sorry if I was unclear.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your are not giving a value to people : you make an instance of ArrayList but that's all. Try making a query once you are connected to your database : `SELECT * FROM PeoplesInfo` and then check the result of this query to see if your table is empty or not.

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a simple order of operation problem to me.

This code should happen before you check to see if the people array is empty.

```
resultSet = statement
    .executeQuery("SELECT name, bio, image FROM PeoplesInfo");

while (resultSet.next()) {

    Person p = new Person(resultSet.getString("name"),resultSet.getString("bio"),resultSet.getString("image"));
    people.add(p);

    System.out.println(p.toString());
    System.out.println("Retrieved element is = " + p.getName());       

}
```

Also it looks like you were trying a couple of different ways so you have the insert command twice when you only need it once.

So then rearranged it should look like this.

```
private ArrayList<Person> people;
public Database(){
    people = new ArrayList<Person>();
}

public void run(){

    Connection connection = null;
    ResultSet resultSet = null;
    Statement statement = null;


    try {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        connection = DriverManager
            .getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\Peopleinfo.sqlite");


        statement = connection.createStatement();
        resultSet = statement
            .executeQuery("SELECT name, bio, image FROM PeoplesInfo");

        while (resultSet.next()) {

            Person p = new Person(resultSet.getString("name"),resultSet.getString("bio"),resultSet.getString("image"));
            people.add(p);

            System.out.println(p.toString());
            System.out.println("Retrieved element is = " + p.getName());       

        }

        if(people.isEmpty()){
            String sql = "INSERT INTO PeoplesInfo (Name,bio,Image) " +
                "VALUES ('John','California','C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\images\\upload.png');"; 
            statement.executeUpdate(sql);
            System.out.println("Record added");

            File f = new File ("C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\images\\upload.png");

            if (f.exists()){
                System.out.println("Image exists");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("Image doesn't exist");
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            resultSet.close();
            statement.close();
            connection.close();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}


public ArrayList<Person> getPeople(){
    return people;
}
```

Comment: i'm trying to check the results from the table instead of the array. This is currently what i've tried and it gives me a index out of bounds error. rSt = statement
              .executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PeoplesInfo");
         
         if(rSt == null ){
             String sql = "INSERT INTO PeoplesInfo (Name,bio,Image) " +
                 "VALUES ('John','California','C:\\Users\\James\\Documents\\GoogleApp\\images\\upload.png');"; 
             statement.executeUpdate(sql);
             System.out.println("Record added");